# Restrict systemd service accessing files

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, systemd, restrict

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am creating systemd service to start python code. But, the problem is that, I don't want my python code to have access to other directories except where it is running. It would be good to restrict systemd service or python to have access to another directories. I am worried that other files on Ubuntu server may be deleted or corrupted.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So run your Python code as a user that only has access to the files you want?

Comment: Yes. Access only to that files.

Comment: Anyone has an option?

Comment: Still no solution :/

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it's not clear what you've tried. I suggested running the service as a specific user that only has access to those specific directories. Did you try that? Did it work? Did it not work?